# Parse file "/proc/net/route" contents

Tags: android

How to parse the content of /proc/net/route file for android.

I am using "cat" command to read the file

```
 `process proc_route = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/net/route");`
```

It shows the output like this

```
Iface Destination Gateway Flags RefCnt Use Metric Mask Mtu Window IRTT       
eth0  0202000A 00000000 0005 0 0 0 FFFFFFFF 0 0 0    
eth0  0002000A 00000000 0001 0 0 0 FFFFFFFF 0 0 0       
eth0  00000000 00000000 0003 0 0 0 00000000 0 0 0
```

I want the output to be like

```
Iface Destination Gateway  Flags RefCnt Use   Metric Mask               Mtu Window IRTT    
eth0  10.0.2.2    0.0.0.0  0005  0      0     0      255.255.255.255    0   0      0
eth0  10.0.2.0    0.0.0.0  0001  0      0     0      255.255.255.255    0   0      0
eth0  10.0.0.0    0.0.0.0  0003  0      0     0      0.0.0.0            0   0      0
```

Is there a command or utility for this?

Comment: have you figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

This link can guide you further if someone else if looking for the solution to this problem [Odd Bits](http://blog.oddbit.com/2015/03/08/converting-hexadecimal-ip-addresses-to-dotted-quads-with-bas/). Basically the address is in little endian hex form and you need to convert it to decimal dotted form.